# Runtime of the program

Tags: algorithm, runtime

```
for i from 1 to n*n do
 j=n
 while j > 0 do
   j--
```

I figured out the runtime tightly to be $$\Theta(n^6)$$ if we use summations, but I am not sure if that is correct. Any pointers?

Comment: It is not correct. Note that `i` doesn't participate in the inner loop, so it is quite easy to compute the number of iterations per outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation of run-time will be like this:

- First for loop for `i from 1 to n*n do` iterates total **n*n** times.
- Second while loop
  `j=n
  while j > 0 do
  j--`
  iterates total **n** times.

So, total run-time will be comparable to O(n*n)*O(n) = **O(n^3)**.